# delete some dimension from multi-dimentional array with xarray

Tags: python, arrays, filtering, python-xarray

I have an array that looks like this:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:            (step: 40, latitude: 62, longitude: 126)
Coordinates:
    time               datetime64[ns] ...
  * step               (step) timedelta64[ns] 0 days 06:00:00 ... 10 days 00:...
    heightAboveGround  float64 ...
  * latitude           (latitude) float64 28.4 28.0 27.6 27.2 ... 4.8 4.4 4.0
  * longitude          (longitude) float64 -160.8 -160.4 ... -111.2 -110.8
    valid_time         (step) datetime64[ns] dask.array<chunksize=(24,), meta=np.ndarray>
Data variables:
    u10                (step, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(24, 14, 24), meta=np.ndarray>
    v10                (step, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(24, 14, 24), meta=np.ndarray>
Attributes:
    GRIB_edition:            2
    GRIB_centre:             ecmf
    GRIB_centreDescription:  European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts
    GRIB_subCentre:          0
    Conventions:             CF-1.7
    institution:             European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts
    history:                 2023-07-14T14:26 GRIB to CDM+CF via cfgrib-0.9.1...
```

The dimension `step` has a size of 40 but I am only interested in a few of them and want to drop the rest.

I want to filter out `step` by the values in a list called `timePeriod_list` . I have tried the following but it gives me an error.

```
timePeriod_list = [6, 12]

xarr_steps = xarr.where([(xarr.step != i) for i in timePeriod_list], drop=True)
print(xarr_steps)
```

error message:

```
File "C:\Users\Giacomo\PycharmProjects\HIT-v3\try_bufr_enfo.py", line 338, in <module>
    xarr_steps = xarr1.where([(xarr1.step != i) for i in timePeriod_list], drop=True)
  File "C:\Users\Giacomo\anaconda3\envs\HIT-v3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\common.py", line 1121, in where
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: cond argument is [<xarray.DataArray 'step' (step: 40)>
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True])
Coordinates:
    time               datetime64[ns] ...
  * step               (step) timedelta64[ns] 0 days 06:00:00 ... 10 days 00:...
    heightAboveGround  float64 ...
    valid_time         (step) datetime64[ns] dask.array<chunksize=(24,), meta=np.ndarray>, <xarray.DataArray 'step' (step: 40)>
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True])
Coordinates:
    time               datetime64[ns] ...
  * step               (step) timedelta64[ns] 0 days 06:00:00 ... 10 days 00:...
    heightAboveGround  float64 ...
    valid_time         (step) datetime64[ns] dask.array<chunksize=(24,), meta=np.ndarray>] but must be a <class 'xarray.core.dataset.Dataset'> or <class 'xarray.core.dataarray.DataArray'>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved by making a loop and then combining the arrays by the `step` dimension

```
xarr_steps = []
for x in xarr.coords['step'].values:
    if x in timePeriod_list:
        xarr.sel(step=mask).squeeze(drop=True)
        new_da = xarr.where(xarr.step == x, drop=True)
        xarr_steps.append(new_da)

combined = xr.combine_nested(xarr_steps, concat_dim=["step"])
```